# How to Install Game Boy Advance Emulator on my iPhone 6

Tags: iphone, games

I want to play Game Boy Advance games on my iPhone, but I can't install a working Game Boy Advance emulator on my iPhone.

I have iOS 9.2.1 installed on my phone. I searched for tutorials online, but the app can't be installed.

Is there any way to play Game Boy Advance games on an iPhone?

Comment: Have you tried [sideloading](http://bouk.co/blog/sideload-iphone/) GBA4iOS (what I presume you're using?)

Answer (score 1):

There are many emulators out there espeically for Game Boy Advance, but the most current one is [GBA4iOS](http://www.cydiageeks.com/download-install-gba4ios-ios-without-jailbreak.html). Check it out and see if that help.

Answer (score 0):

I use the buildStore :

http://builds.io

$9.99/year/device but you have a lot of emulators (a stable GBA4IOS) and cool apps.

Hope this can help.